# Black squares in Skype Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, graphics, skype

[Screen Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Had4r.png)
Can anyone explain the attached image? Only happens in Skype. Used to occur in Chromium until I turned off hardware acceleration in Chromium settings.
All packages and snaps are up-to-date.
Info from system:

```
    $ glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_query_renderer, GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, 
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
OpenGL renderer string: ATI RV370
    GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_copy_image, 
    GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_sliced_3d, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, GL_OES_get_program_binary, GL_OES_mapbuffer, 


$ sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: RV370 [Radeon X300]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

Comment: In case you are using the snap, check if the problem persists in .deb or flatpak